# Unique matrix ID and fast checking

Tags: matrix, sorting, hashing

I have the following problem :

I have a programm which can generate a lot of 3x3 matrices whose elements take integer values in [-3;3], example :{{1,2,3},{-3,0,-2},{1,1,1}}.

Each time my programm generates a Matrix M, I want to store it in a storage structure L.
The thing is, if my programm generates a second time the matrix M, I do not want to add it again to the list.

Therefore each time I generate a matrix, I must compare through some sort of identification if the matrix  M already exists in my list L.

Therefore I would like to have a unique ID for each matrix, which ensures a fast verfification of whether or not the newly generated matrix exists in the storage structure L.

I have heard of hashing (I am not from the programming world). 
So my idea is the following:

I generate M,

I calculate Hash[M]

Then I add the association Hash[M]->M to a list L.

If I generate a second matrix M', I calculate Hash [M'], and I check if the key Hash[M'] exists in L, if not I add the association Hash[M']->M' to L etc..

The thing is I am not sure the hash function is a bijection (I think it's not).

Second, I do not know how fast the checking part ("check if the key Hash[M'] exists in L") is !
My list is going to be big, so I need the checking to be efficient !!

Can anyone enlighten me or give me a better faster solution?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Hashes are generally not bijective.  Faced with your problem I might roll my own 'hash-like' operation such as `FromDigits[4 + Flatten[M]]` and keep  those 9-digit integers in your list `L`.  As to the speed of this approach, I'm not sure and not in a position to test right now, which is why I'm only commenting.  While you wait for an answer, do some research into *Bloom filters*.

Comment: Do you really need to do this each time a new matrix is generated? If not, then a simple thing to do is to generate all the matrices, and take the Union[ ]. This will remove all the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `Association` e.g. as follows:

```
input = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {100000, 3, 3}];

ClearAll[a];
a = Association[];
Do[a[A] = 1;, {A, input}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
output1 = Keys[a];
```

> 0.173041

Internally `Association` uses hashes and quite many other tricks to make the addition, modification, and lookup of entries efficient.

Alternatively, you can use the hash table that manages the `DownValues` of a symbol as follows:

```
ClearAll[a];
Do[a[A] = 1;, {A, input}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
output2 = Extract[DownValues[a][[All, 1]], {All, 1, 1}];
```

> 0.189094

Both are equally fast and produce the same result up to ordering:

```
Sort[output1] == Sort[output2]
```

> True

I prefer the first method because an `Association` is a more structured and encapsulated way of storing data; it can be easily erased with `a=.` and be send to other functions/contexts etc. without having to mess around with the *Mathematica's* name space management.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I do not really understand the downValues thing, so I'll go with the first alternative for now.

Comment: You're welcome.